# Find what the parent of an unparented task was in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there a way to query product backlog items (and their histories) to find what the parent of an unparented task was before the link was deleted?

For instance here I have two tasks that are showing up as unparented.

[image: ADO Sprint board showing unparented tasks]

They used to be parented to a user story but the link has been broken. Rather than having to trawl all my user stories and look through the history, I would like to be able to run a query (for instance on item 253152) and it to tell me what the parent used to be.

Update 07 Apr 2022:

Miao Tian's answer is of course absolutely correct.

In our case the tasks appear to have never been parented. They where created by a third party tool which appears to have failed to link them correctly. I'll post more information if it is helpful when we get to the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to find the parent of this work item in the past, you don't need to use query. You can directly open item 253152 to view its history.
example:

start

[image]

delete the link

[image]

check the history of the task and find the parent

[image]